# I have minimum value and maximum value text box put a check that minimum value cannot be greater than maximum value .S

Tags: vb.net

I have minimum value text box and maximum value text box of all chemical elements name i want to put a check that minimum value cannot be greater than maximum value .So,need help.

Comment: Show your code!, where you want to put checking ?, Does your two text boxes accept only number ??

Comment: There is also the check that maximum cannot be less than minimum since both values entered by user. One is relative to other, so I believe that you have to validate them as pair of values for more detailed error message for the user. I would perform a validation on save - update.

Answer (score 0):

To handle both textbox accept only numbers(*optional*)

```
Private Sub txtMIN_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) _
    Handles txtMIN.KeyPress, txtMAX.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.KeyChar = ""
        End If
    End Sub
```

For the checking :

You can use [val()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx) function : - *Returns the numbers contained in a string as a numeric value of appropriate type*

```
    Private Sub txtMIN_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles txtMIN.Leave, txtMAX.Leave 
            If Trim(txtMIN.Text) <> String.Empty AndAlso Trim(txtMAX.Text) <> String.Empty Then
            If Val(txtMIN.Text) > Val(txtMAX.Text) Then
                MsgBox("Min value cannot be greater than max value")
                txtMIN.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I have multiple min and Max text boxes like carbon's min text box ,max text box then sulfur's min text box - max text box ,there are 24 chemical elements name.I want the answer in multiple  way.

Comment: @PRITAMBERIHA I cant write blind code here because you have not provided the code. Aforementioned answer is the basic way to do the task

Comment: Private Function rangecheck()
        Try
            If Val(txtCarbonMin.Text) > Val(txtCarbonMax.Text) Then
                lblMessage.Text = "Carbon Minimum Value Cannot be Greater Than Maximum Value"
                Return False
            End If     If Val(txtAntimonyMin.Text) > Val(txtAntimonyMax.Text) Then
                lblMessage.Text = "Antimony Minimum Value Cannot be Greater Than Maximum Value"
                Return False
            End If          
...........
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

Comment: i created manually for all elements but i want to reduce the code .thank u

Comment: Make a function like this -  http://hastebin.com/ujilejurat.vbs and  call it whenever you want like this `CHECK_MIN_MAX(txtCarbonMin, txtCarbonMax)`

Comment: Values are not passing through the function

Comment: @PRITAMBERIHA That function will work I don't know what happening in your side.. another way  - http://hastebin.com/ozotuzijeq.vbs